# Nested Type Not Receiving User Input From Parent

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a nested type in my GraphQL schema using AWS AppSync console. For example: in the function, the user should enter a ID and optionally lang. That lang should then be used to help identity the subtitle. However after setting up my schema and resolver like the following: every time I run a query, it returns the result with all langs (when it should only returned the ID and lang that's specified by the user). I'm not sure why this is, when I separate the function and it's not nested, this same schema and resolver works. please help!!! (I'm using Elastic Search)

```
type Query {
  getVideo(ID: String, lang: String): [video]
}

type video {
  mainId: ID
  title: String
  subtitles: [subtitles]
}

type subtitles {
  childId: ID
  lang: String
  caption: Boolean
}
```

This my request resolver--**that's attached to video.subtitles**--below (the response mapping template is the standard one when generating a list for ES):

```
{
"version": "2018-02-28",
"operation": "GET",
"path":"/lang/lang/_search",
#if(!$context.arguments.lang)
"params": {}
#else
"params": {
   "body": {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
           {"match" : {"lang.keyword" : "${context.args.lang}" }}
           ]
         }
       }
     }
    }
  #end
  }
```

This the query that I am running. I only want the results that match the ID and the lang specified:

```
query vid(ID: "1234", lang: "eng") {
    subtitles {
       lang
       caption
    }
 }
```

Now the following is the result: notice how it returns ALL langs instead of just eng. I'm not sure why this is **please help!**

```
{
  "data":
     "getVideo": [
         "subtitles" : [
            {
              "lang": "dutch",
              "caption": "false"
            },
           {
              "lang": "eng",
             "caption": "true"
           },
           {
              "lang": "span",
              "caption": "true",
           }
      ]
    ]
   }
```

Comment: You question is unclear. It would be better if you can share example documents and expected result.

Comment: @NishantSaini I have updated the title and description and provided the query that I'm running and the results that keep generating. From results, it should ONLY return lang that is equal to eng not everything,

Comment: Seems like the subtitle field is array type and not nested type. Thats why every item of array is returned.

Comment: @NishantSaini hmm.. when I just changed subtitles from a array type, the result now return everything as null. What foes a nested type look like?

Comment: Please add mapping of index to the question. Changes in mapping will be required to get the desired result.

Comment: @NishantSaini I'm not following. How does the change in request mapping affect what gets return when regardless I need to match the platform with what the user request? The response mapping is the one that AWS generated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your message but when you want to return a nested object, you must to use [Inner Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-request-inner-hits.html).

You can also set your field _source to retrieve only inner hits.

Comment: I'm reading the article and I'm a little confused, in the sense of AWS AppSync.. what name do I use to refer to the original parent type video? So it's know that subtitles is the child of that parent?

Comment: Hi @C.Lewis, well I don't know nothing about AppSync but I see your "request resolve" you have an elasticSearch search query. First, you want to get only the objects "hitted" by your query right? If yes, your elasticsearch mapping must consider subtitles as a nested object. And then you will use inner_hits in your request resolver.